# Reference request: Vanishing of first cohomology term in Riemann-Roch theorem for singular projective curves over a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, divisors, invertible-sheaves

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}$
$\newcommand{\ox}{\mathcal{O}_X}$
Let $f:X \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ be a projective scheme of dimension one over a field $k$. The Riemann-Roch equation for such curves is given, for instance in Liu's book (Thm. 7.3.26), and it states

$$ h^0(\F) - h^1(\F) = \deg_k \F + \chi(\ox)$$

for $\F$ an invertible $\ox$-module. Moreover, we have $h^1(\F) = h^0(\omega_f \otimes_{\ox} \F^{-1})$ where $\omega_f$ denotes the $1$-dualizing sheaf of $f$.

I am looking for a reference which states the following:

> In the above situation, we have $$ h^0(\F) = \deg_k \F + \chi(\ox)$$ whenever $\deg_k \F$ is greater than a bound solely depending on $X$, for instance a constant multiple of $\chi(\ox)$.

Liu does give such a statement in his book, but he needs to assume that $X$ is a local complete intersection and, moreover, integral. But I wonder whether this is true in a more general setting.

---

**Edit**
If $X$ is Gorenstein, this is easily seen to be true. In particular, I am interested in the case that $X$ is **not** Gorenstein.

Comment: If your curve is not irreducible, you are in trouble — Gorenstein or not.

Comment: @abx Could you please elaborate why this is the case? I am grateful for any kind of insight.

Comment: Suppose for instance that your curve is the union of 2 smooth components $A$ and $B$, meeting transversally at a point $p$. Take a line bundle of negative degree on $A$, and very large  degree on $B$, so that the total degree is as large as you want. Then there will be nonzero sections in $H^0(A,\omega_A(p) \otimes \mathcal{F}^{-1})$ vanishing at $p$. Just extend these sections by $0$ on $B$.

Comment: @abx Thank you, that makes sense! So what if we assume $\mathcal{F}$ to be ample? Then what you've mentioned cannot happen anymore.

Comment: Yes it can — just take a line bundle of degree 1 on $A$, and very large on $B$, and do the same construction.

Comment: @abx Why do you still have non-zero elements in $\operatorname{H}^0(A,\omega_A \otimes \mathcal{F}^{-1})$ in that example? Aren't the latter the global sections of a negative degree divisor on $A$ and therefore zero? Where do I miss something?

Comment: You miss that $\omega _A$ has degree $2g(A)-2$.

Comment: @abx True, true! So, is it then plausible to think that assuming sufficiently large degree of $\mathcal{F}$ on the irreducible components suffices?

Comment: Yes, this will work.